# Is there a way to tell VisualStudio to ignore all compilation errors in a specific css file inside a website project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a dynamically generated css file that contain in addition to the CSS code markup for my generation. Those markup cause VisualStudio to report on compilation errors of the css.

Is there any way to tell VS to ignore errors from that file - while kipping it inside the website and keeping it a css file (i do not want to lose the editing features of VS for css

i will expand the question: is there a way to tell VS to edit some other new extension using existing highlight and code completion without compiling it? i can live very well with a new extension that i will make up

Comment: lol i'd like to know this as well

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615058/how-to-make-the-visual-studio-compiler-ignore-a-file

Comment: The link you provide isn't good - since the project i am talking about is a website - that means there is no project file to store build actions (the closest thing to that is the web.config file) there is the exclude/include mechanism within the VS but that renames the file with a new extension and then VS does not give any CSS aids when editing the file - instead it regards it as a simple txt file