# Stop showing SQL errors in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

How can I stop VS2010 showing errors in .sql files, attached to a project? I don't want to check them at all, just C# code. The files are used as resources, Build Action set to Content. I'd like to keep .sql extension for syntax coloring purpose.

Regards,

Comment: Is this just a Visual Studio UI question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615058/how-to-make-the-visual-studio-compiler-ignore-a-file

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such option ("Validation") for SQL. Only for HTML. I mean Scott's article (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/23/431350.aspx) from the question you pointed. Also, I'm not sure, can I set Build Action no None, if I still want to link the files as resources and does it help, but I'll try.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Looks like your question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8593877/2798869:

### Visual Studio 2010

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> IntelliSense`

Uncheck "Enable IntelliSense".

### Visual Studio 2012 & 2013

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> SQL Server Tools -> IntelliSense`

Uncheck "Underline errors"

Note that you have to close then re-open any .sql files you may have open.

Comment: You only have to uncheck "Underline Errors".  You can leave the rest on, if you want.

Answer (score 15):

In VS 2012.

1. Go to the sql file properties in VS.
2. Under "Advanced", change the "Build Action" option to "None".

Unfortunately you have to do this for each sql file in the project.

This is what gave me the behavior that I wanted.  It not only compiles without errors but shows no sql related build errors.

**Update**

It is possible to select multiple files in Solution Explorer by using `Shift + Click` (select the file at the top of the list -> hold down shift -> click the file at the bottom of the list). Once you have selected the group of files, you can then change the Build action to None for all of them at once. (This worked for me in VS2013.)

While you still have to select files ***per folder*** you don't have to select ***each*** file to set the property.

Comment: Worked great for me. A few side notes:  You must close the file, if it's loaded in the editor.  Also, this works in VS2015.

Comment: Build action set to none seem to break the Schema comparison. I need the schema comparison, so I can't use this solution. :(

Answer (score 8):

## VS2015

right click in editor of the sql file > **Intellisense Enabled**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

May be a sledge hammer to the problem but I manually deploy my SQL changes and only use them to house the scripts for my builds, so I do not need the functionality provided by SQL Projects.

Open the VS Solution File properties (right-click the solution in VS Solution Explorer and select Properties) and in the left pane select "Configuration Properties" -> "Configuration". In the right-pane you will see the projects in the solution. Un-check these projects to prevent them from building, this will prevent them from showing errors.

[image: Build Configuration Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you have a .cs extension on those files but it's not shown?   I added some .sql files to my project and the compiler is not complaining.

[image: screen shot of my project]

Comment: Yeah, it looks just fine.  When you add a .cs to the file name, then it complains with a squiggly under "select" and won't compile.

Comment: Though this is extremely annoying, this only happens if the .sql file is open when you try to compile.

Comment: @DaveBlack:  No way...  You're absolutely right.  Setting an SQL "Build Action" to "None" seems to be ignored when the file is open in VS2013.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of files to content and then the intellisense will never try and parse the contents of the files.

Comment: Type of files? "Build Action" or something else?

Comment: I dont have visual studio installed where I am just now, but right click the file properties and there is a I think compile or maybe build option.  Change this to content and it will not try and parse the SQL file.  Same method you would use for webmethod .cs files.

Comment: I already did this to no avail. Please see my question: "Build Action set to Content".

Comment: I am not sure then, I tried setting build action to content in VS 2010 and in VS 2012 and the intellisense is not trying to parse them.  I am not sure if it has anything to do with that I have SQL server data tools installed for 2010 and 2012.

Comment: I guess, 2012 only. Which is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just built a test project with one class file .cs and added one .sql file.  It automatically set the build type to content.  It built fine like John Fraser said in VS2010, so I changed it to compile, and obviously it failed.

This isn't the answer yet but perhaps the next step is to try and create a new solution, and import a few of the files from the original project to try to narrow down the source of the problem.  If it builds then it would tell you it is something about the settings in your project/solution.   Otherwise it could also be a VS setting.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to stop showing SQL errors in bulk:

1. Open the SQL project file which has the `.sqlproj` extension in a text editor.
2. Find and replace `<Build Include=` with `<None Include=`. (This one has the same effect as right-clicking and changing Build Action to None in the solution explorer.)
3. The SQL errors should disappear in Visual Studio.